# How to install Advanced Copy (patch GNU coreutils) in Google Colab

Tags: unix, google-colaboratory

So, I found this [guide](https://ostechnix.com/advanced-copy-add-progress-bar-to-cp-and-mv-commands-in-linux/) to install Advanced Copy on Unix-like systems, but It's giving me errors (maybe at the point when I'm trying to apply the patch) when I'm following the given guide. Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

```
can't find file to patch at input line 4
Perhaps you used the wrong -p or --strip option?
The text leading up to this was:
--------------------------
|diff -aur coreutils-8.32/src/copy.c coreutils-8.32-patched/src/copy.c
|--- coreutils-8.32/src/copy.c  2020-01-01 15:13:12.000000000 +0100
|+++ coreutils-8.32-patched/src/copy.c  2021-08-11 19:48:19.008225844 +0200
--------------------------
File to patch: 
Skip this patch? [y] 
Skipping patch.
11 out of 11 hunks ignored
can't find file to patch at input line 361
Perhaps you used the wrong -p or --strip option?
The text leading up to this was:
--------------------------
|diff -aur coreutils-8.32/src/copy.h coreutils-8.32-patched/src/copy.h
|--- coreutils-8.32/src/copy.h  2020-01-01 15:13:12.000000000 +0100
|+++ coreutils-8.32-patched/src/copy.h  2021-08-11 19:40:37.729820358 +0200
--------------------------
File to patch: 
Skip this patch? [y] 
Skipping patch.
2 out of 2 hunks ignored
can't find file to patch at input line 390
Perhaps you used the wrong -p or --strip option?
The text leading up to this was:
--------------------------
|diff -aur coreutils-8.32/src/cp.c coreutils-8.32-patched/src/cp.c
|--- coreutils-8.32/src/cp.c    2020-01-01 15:13:12.000000000 +0100
|+++ coreutils-8.32-patched/src/cp.c    2021-08-11 19:40:37.729820358 +0200
--------------------------
File to patch: 
Skip this patch? [y] 
Skipping patch.
7 out of 7 hunks ignored
can't find file to patch at input line 555
Perhaps you used the wrong -p or --strip option?
The text leading up to this was:
--------------------------
|diff -aur coreutils-8.32/src/mv.c coreutils-8.32-patched/src/mv.c
|--- coreutils-8.32/src/mv.c    2020-01-01 15:13:12.000000000 +0100
|+++ coreutils-8.32-patched/src/mv.c    2021-08-11 19:40:37.729820358 +0200
--------------------------
File to patch: 
Skip this patch? [y] 
Skipping patch.
5 out of 5 hunks ignored
```

Comment: The diff applied fine for me. Are you calling `patch` exactly how that tutorial does?

Comment: Yes, 'exactly'. Should I change something? @Shawn